# Polymorphism and inheritance in Avro schemas

Tags: java, avro

Is it possible to write an Avro schema/IDL that will generate a Java class that either extends a base class or implements an interface? 
It seems like the generated Java class extends the `org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase`. So, the implements might be the way to go. But, I don't know if this is possible.

I have seen examples with suggestions to define an explicit "type" field in each specific schema, with more of an association than inheritance semantics.

I use my base class heavily in my factory classes and other parts of the code with generics like `<T extends BaseObject>`. Currently, I had it code generated from the JSON Schema, which supports inheritance.

Another side question: can you use IDL to define just records without the protocol definition? I think the answer is no because the compiler complains about the missing protocol keyword.

Help appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found a better way to solve this problem. Looking at the Schema generation source in Avro, I figured out that internally the class generation logic uses Velocity schemas to generate the classes.

I modified the `record.vm` template to also implement my specific interface. There is a way to specify the location of velocity directory using the `templateDirectory` configuration in the maven build plugin.

I also switched to using `SpecificDatumWriter` instead of `reflectDatumWriter`.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${avro.version}</version>
   <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>schema</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
         <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/avro/schema</sourceDirectory>
         <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/java-gen</outputDirectory>
         <fieldVisibility>private</fieldVisibility>
         <stringType>String</stringType>
         <templateDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/avro/velocity-templates/</templateDirectory>
       </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Still looking for some inheritance solution at the schema level (getting pretty sure there is none), but I'm very happy you documented your own findings. Thank you!

Comment: In the templates directory there is a file record.vm

This is a template of the class to be generated, you can alter the template if required.

Here you can include some custom inheritance, or create your own template.

Answer (score 5):

I hope it will be helpful for others if I'll write it here that I've created maven plugin for exactly this case - https://github.com/tunguski/interfacer.

It goes through auto generated classes and check do they conform to interfaces found on classpath in specific package. If yes, interface is added to the class. It works with generic interfaces, at least in basic examples I had to deal with.

The plugin is not avro specific, works as a generated code post processor, so it may be used in other cases too.

```xml
<!-- 
  post process avro generated sources and add interfaces from package
  pl.matsuo.interfacer.showcase to every generated class that has 
  all methods from specific interface
 -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>pl.matsuo.interfacer</groupId>
    <artifactId>interfacer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <interfacesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</interfacesDirectory>
                <interfacePackage>pl.matsuo.interfacer.showcase</interfacePackage>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-interfaces</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

```java
// src/main/java manually defined interface
public interface HasName {
  String getName();
}

// target/generated-sources/avro
public class Person {

  String name;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  // [...]
}

public class Company {

  String name;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  // [...]
}

// after this plugin run

// target/generated-sources/avro
public class Person implements HasName {

  String name;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  // [...]
}

public class Company implements HasName {

  String name;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  // [...]
}
```

Comment: You made my day.

Answer (score 3):

I found this question having similar problem. In my case I needed just to impose *marker interface* and only to *some* types (to distinguish particular classes later). Thanks to your answer, I dug deeper into structure of `record.vm` template. I found out it's possible to define `"javaAnnotation": "my.full.AnnotationName"` key in `.avsc` definition JSON. `@my.full.AnnotationName` is then added to generated class.

Admittedly, this solution is not built on marker interface finally, though for my purpose is good enough and keeping template untouched is big advantage.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to use the `ReflectData` API to generate the Schema from the class at runtime and then use the `ReflectDatumWriter` for serialization. 
Use of reflection will be slower. But, it looks like the schema is cached internally. I will report back if I see performance issues.

```
Schema schema = ReflectData.AllowNull.get().getSchema(sourceObject.getClass());
ReflectDatumWriter<T> reflectDatumWriter = new ReflectDatumWriter<>(schema);

DataFileWriter<T> writer = new DataFileWriter<>(reflectDatumWriter);
try {
    writer.setCodec(CodecFactory.snappyCodec());
    writer.create(schema, new File("data.avro"));
    writer.append(sourceObject);
    writer.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // log exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an avro-maven-plugin [extension](https://github.com/sabomichal/avro-compiler-extension) available to solve your problem, specifically to add a custom interface to generated avro record Java class.

Answer (score -2):

I followed https://www.infoq.com/articles/ApacheAvro/ for implementing inheritance. This put lights on polymorphism as well(which i needed).

One point. 
While declaring 
`{"name": "user", "type": com.navteq.avro.FacebookUser },`
make sure you double quote , like `{"name": "user", "type": "com.navteq.avro.FacebookUser" },`

If i do not do that, then i was getting error like below

`> org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('c' (code 99)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')`